# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2 [keras]

Tags: machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I got the error: `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2` with the following code:

```
def make_model():
  model = Sequential()      

  model.add(Conv2D(20,(5,5), input_shape = (24,48,30), activation = "relu", strides = 1, padding = "valid"))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))        
  model.add(Conv2D(50, (5,5), use_bias = 50))    
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))    
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(20, activation = "relu"))
  model.add(LSTM(50, activation="relu", return_sequences=True))

  return model
```

My input is 30 matrices of size 24*48 each.

Comment: Try to use `input_shape=(24, 48)`

Comment: nah, that isn't working. Gives the error `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3`

Comment: George is right, you shouldn't specify number of data you have in your models. If problem persists refer to : https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/

Comment: Check what you give as x_train and x_validation in your model.fit() call, Their size should be (30,24,48) not (24,48,30) . 

input_shape = (24,48,30) should be input_shape = (24,48)

Comment: @yaminigoel:What is the shape of X_train?

Comment: @George See I am very new to this field of ML, this is my 1st model so pardon me for my stupid questions & replies. 
I am kinda confused about the shape of X_train. My problem is I have many users, each has 30 matrices of shape(24,48). Now for 1user, I want 1 answer from the model. So ideally X_train is (24,48) but then there are 30 such matrices for which I need just 1 O/P. I think I either change the shape of X_train or may be modify the model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that after the last Dense layer (before the lstm layer), the output shape is (?, 20) and the lstm layer expects 3D tensor, not 2D.So, you can expand the dimensions in order to add one more before feeding to lstm layer.

You can expand dimensions using tf.expand_dims (assuming you use tensorflow as backend) [tf expand](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims)

```
input_layer = Input((30,24,48))

model = Conv2D(20,(5,5), input_shape = (30,24,48), activation = "relu", strides = 1, padding = "valid")(input_layer)
model = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(model)        
model = Conv2D(50, (5,5), use_bias = 50)(model)    
model = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(model)  
model = Flatten()(model)
model = Dense(20, activation = "relu")(model)
model = tf.expand_dims(model, axis=-1)
model = LSTM(50, activation="relu", return_sequences=True)(model)
```

(I didn't use Sequential mode, I am using [functional api](https://keras.io/models/model/) since it is more flexible)

If you want to use sequential model:

```
    model = Sequential()      

    model.add(Conv2D(20,(5,5), input_shape = (30, 24, 48), activation = "relu", strides = 1, padding = "valid"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))        
    model.add(Conv2D(50, (5,5), use_bias = 50))    
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))    
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(20, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(model.output, axis=-1)))
    model.add(LSTM(50, activation="relu", return_sequences=True))
```

you must use expand dims inside [Lambda](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda)

Comment: it works fine if I use functional API, but in Sequential mode it gives me the following error `TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'> to Tensor. Contents: <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7f44e3530668>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.` for `model = tf.expand_dims(model, axis=-1)`. I need to use Sequential mode, can you help me there?

Comment: Hi @George! Your answer solved my problem. I was kinda confused at some other level and I believe you could answer me. I have "n" vectors of equal sizes, how can I combine them to feed them to RNN. I mean vectors are 2d and I have n such 2d vectors and I need to send them to an RNN, can you tell me how can I achieve this? Also I don't wish to concat them, I need 'n' vectors of specific size into the RNN layer.